# ImportError: No module named 'RPi'

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am trying to make a humidity sensor using this code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# read data using pin 14
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=17)

while True:
    result = instance.read()
    if result.is_valid():
        print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
        print("Temperature: %d F" % ((result.temperature * 9/5)+32))
        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

    time.sleep(1)
```

However I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dht11_example.py", line 1, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named 'RPi'
```

I am pretty sure I've installed RPi already, I use a Raspberry Pi 3 B model.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit:
this is the output I get 
python-rpi.gpio-dbgsym 
python3-rpi.gpio
python-rpi.gpio 
python3-rpi.gpio-dbgsym

Thanks for your response, I am pretty sure it's a full raspbian. How do I uninstall it for Python 2 and reinstall it for Python 3? I am not sure, but I think I installed it for Python 3. It's a 3+ B Model. Sorry for that. I've tried multiple things but I still get the same error.

Comment: oh yeah the file name is dht11_example.py and I get the error after running it with python dht11_example.py I've tried searching for errors and other people who solve it but it doesn't work.

Comment: run `apt-cache pkgnames | grep rpi.gpio` - do you get any output?

Comment: @Jaromanda X this is the output I get
python-rpi.gpio-dbgsym
python3-rpi.gpio
python-rpi.gpio
python3-rpi.gpio-dbgsym

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am pretty sure it's a full raspbian. How do I uninstall it for Python 2 and reinstall it for Python 3? I am not sure, but I think I installed it for Python 3. It's a 3+ B Model. Sorry for that. I've tried multiple things but I still get the same error.

Comment: If you are the same user as the OP "hola1234567890", please edit your question and add it, or add a comment. Please don't post this as an answer. This is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: Please use the comments, or edit and update your question. This is not an answer.

Comment: Have you got three accounts and two accounts with the same name? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/90439/hola1234567890 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/90408/hola1234567890? Also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/90438/user90438?

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

RPi.GPIO is pre-installed for Python 2 and Python 3 on the full Raspbian.  I'm not sure about Raspbian lite.

If you are not using the full Raspbian you should indicate so in your question.

The likeliest error is that you have installed it for Python 2 and are trying to use it in Python 3 or vice versa.